# Copying from remote servers to local server

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do an unattended backup our websites from 2 webservers to our backup server.

```
$FolderName = $(Get-Date -Format D)
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName\ColoWebP1
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName\ColoWebD1

Copy-Item \\colowebp1.wa.local\e$\websites D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName\ColoWebP1 -recurse
Copy-Item \\colowebp1.wa.local\e$\backup D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName\ColoWebP1 -recurse
Copy-Item \\colowebd1.wa.local\e$\websites D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName\ColoWebD1 -recurse
Copy-Item \\colowebd1.wa.local\e$\backup D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName\ColoWebD1 -recurse
```

Now I still have not got this to run unattended.  It creates the folders but does not copy the files.  And now a new wrinkle has occured.  When I run it manually I recieve this error:

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path 'D:\backups\webservers\Tuesday, February 25, 2014\ColoWebD1\websites\Agent_eVantage_Beta
\Master_wSlider.master' is denied.
At C:\scripts\Webserverbackup.ps1:12 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  \\colowebd1.wa.local\e$\websites D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName\ColoWebD1 -recurse
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (Master_wSlider.master:FileInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyFileInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

But all the files appear to be there. (I haven't attempted a restore of this yet).

So my questions are:
Am I reading this error right? Is it having trouble authenticating to the server this is running from?

And how do I get this to run unattended?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the dollar sign in your Copy-Item (i.e. `\$e\`)

PowerShell is interpreting the $ sign as a variable. I would instead use a shared folder instead of the drive letter.

```
Copy-Item '\\colowebp1.wa.local\Share\websites' "D:\backups\webservers\$FolderName\ColoWebP1" -recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set proper permissions to access Admin share. What happens when you access the target path above with Explorer? If everything is set up correctly, you should be able to get into the share without authentication. (ex. with default network credentials). Your solution itself is fine however and it will work once the authentication is not required. There are workarounds to this with PS but you would have to provide some details on network and UAC setup. I will happily attempt to resolve this once you provide the details.

At work I use such paths to admin share and these are working perfectly, Powershell doesnt treat the share as a variable.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: I can access the share with explorer no problem. After a reboot I did have to enter my credentials but it started working after that.  I just wanted to setup something so i didnt have to do that every time (although our backup server reboots very infrequently)  Also not sure if it matters but the backup server is on a different domain (was there before i started)